# Twitter analytics API

Tags: php, api, twitter

Is there any way to access Twitter analytics api and data with some kind of php library or something?

I want to access my own account data and I want to create a php app that allows me to get that data and show it in a different way (Html,Css).

I got my tweets and other stuff with his twitter API and with some libraries, but now I need to get data from twitter analytics.

I have read some topics about this in stackoverflow, but social media's api changes all the time and I want to know if it is possible to do this right now, or if someone has discovered a way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No API unfortunately, just a hackish way (Selenium) in Python that I created as a package.

```
$ pip install twitter-analytics
```

More here: https://github.com/philippe2803/twitter-analytics-wrapper